# How to build a closed contour with given length that minimizes the distance to all points that are not included in the contour?

Tags: algorithm, geometry, 2d

Construct a closed contour that will have the smallest distance to all points in the set

I have a regular grid, at the nodes of which there are points. It is required to build from these points a closed contour of a given length or less, so that the points (from grid) not included in the contour have the smallest sum of total distances to the nearest point included in the contour.

I found that up to a certain point it is easiest to make a regular square with the center coinciding with the center of the lattice, but then you have to expand this square inward.

As an example, it is assumed that for a certain length, the contour for the given value 42 should look something like this.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWVIi.png)

Comment: When employing the way "Starting with 1-grid-cell-contour(length is 4) which putted on the "best" position, and dilating one by one cell with greedy method", what is the problem?